# Cant seem to parse json data in React, unsure of any conceptual errors i might

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using materialsUItable to display table data, i am using React as my framework

I am importing a JSON file from a similar root directory, and i am attempting to display data within that json file

```
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import jsondata from "./data.json"



export default function MaterialTableDemo() {

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
      { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
      { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
    ],


 data: [
    jsondata.data.map(Array => Array)
 ]

  });
```

the above method shows no error, yet although the table renders, it merely shows a blank table :/
Could someone explain to me why the data doesnt display?

this was another method i attempted, although there isnt any error displayed, the data doesnt display and a blank table shows up

```
JSON.parse(jsondata)
```

this was another method i tried, but all it displayed was a blank page, the table didnt show up :/

i am really confused at why the data doesnt display, what conceptual errors am i making in trying to display the data?

Comment: you can check the information through your console like regular javascript by simply console.log(jsondata) to check if the data exists or not. And base on official documentation. The structure is like `data: {[  ]}` instead of `[ ]` (I could be wrong for this part without knowing the outputing and accepting data structrue)

Comment: and map function return `array` type so if everything is passed as expected, it will be `data: {  jsondata.data.map(Array => Array) }`

Answer (score 0):

I have not used `material-table` before but I have done a quick look up on its doc [here](https://material-table.com/#/docs/get-started) and they have an example of the data being passed like this

```
data={[{ name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 }]}
```

You can see that `data` is **an object wrapping an array of object**, however here's your code:

```
data: [
  jsondata.data.map(Array => Array)
]
```

I assume you passing the data like this:

```
data={data}
```

since `map` will return an array, you are passing something like this:

```
data={[[*contentOfYourArray*]]}
```

which is **an object wrapping an array of array**, you should write like this instead:

```
data: jsondata.data.map(Array => Array)
```

Also, `data` should be an array of objects, so I assume your `jsondata.data` is an array of object too, so actually...

```
data: jsondata.data
```

Or if you want to do some data massaging:

```
data: jsondata.data.map(object => return {
    name: object.field1,
    surename: object.field2
})
```